# Installing caret for R. nlopt linux install error

Tags: r, linux, installation

I am new to linux and struggling with installing caret for R. I am receiving the following error during the caret install process.

```
configure: Need to download and build NLopt
trying URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url = "http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Execution halted
/bin/gtar: This does not look like a tar archive

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
/bin/gtar: Child returned status 1
/bin/gtar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Warning message:
In untar(tarfile = "nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz") :
  '/bin/gtar -xf 'nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'' returned error code 2
configure: Starting to install library to /tmp/RtmpIT5jNR/R.INSTALL17d113d7c2a/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2
./configure: line 3325: cd: nlopt-2.4.2: No such file or directory
```

It stops after this, floating and then I have to crash R to fix it. I have scoured through the nlopt site and based on the error have attempted to install into R manually. I have the actual tar file and I have placed it into Rstudios package file, then gone through the process of installing it. However, this does not seem to work at all. I am guessing there is something specific to R that needs to be done to complete the install?

Note I have tried installing just the nlopt via install.packages and the same error occurs. Any ideas?

Edit 1:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] nnet_7.3-11      Hmisc_3.17-0     Formula_1.2-1   
 [4] survival_2.38-3  lattice_0.20-33  readxl_0.1.0    
 [7] reshape2_1.4.1   ggplot2_1.0.1    dplyr_0.4.3     
[10] data.table_1.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2         cluster_2.0.3       magrittr_1.5       
 [4] splines_3.2.2       MASS_7.3-43         munsell_0.4.2      
 [7] colorspace_1.2-6    R6_2.1.1            stringr_1.0.0      
[10] plyr_1.8.3          tools_3.2.2         parallel_3.2.2     
[13] gtable_0.1.2        latticeExtra_0.6-26 DBI_0.3.1          
[16] lazyeval_0.1.10     assertthat_0.1      digest_0.6.8       
[19] gridExtra_2.0.0     RColorBrewer_1.1-2  acepack_1.3-3.3    
[22] rpart_4.1-10        stringi_1.0-1       RevoUtils_8.0.0    
[25] scales_0.3.0        foreign_0.8-65      chron_2.3-47       
[28] proto_0.3-10
```

I reconogize I am not using the most recent version of R and unfortunitly will not be able to upgrade. However, Caret package information claims it should work on anything greater than R(>=2.1), lattice(>=0.2) and ggplot2. All of which criteria is met.

Comment: what does `sessionInfo()` in R return?

Comment: @shea I have attached the results.

Comment: I have been in a similar predicament with a package I can't remember on an older version of R on an old version of CentOS. The package had a dependency on `raster` library and because I was working with geotiff files, I needed the `raster` dependency for the package I wanted to work in. The CentOS was on a network that wouldn't let me do a local install and they weren't going to be updating R for a few more months. Is it possible that `caret` has a dependency or suggests something else that is giving you grief for the OS?

Comment: Your question might actually be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985759/cant-install-the-caret-package-in-r-in-my-linux-machine      (and thus a dupe)

Comment: It does look very similar @shea, I am attempting to work through it now. Not gonna lie, its a bit over my head as far as my understanding of linux atm. Might take a little time before I can confirm.